# What could be a plan status higher than "pro"?

Tags: word-usage, connotations

1. I am developing a web application that currently has a pro plan for users. What could be the appropriate word for the next level plan? I do not want to use the word ultimate because the word can restrict potential expansion in the future.
2. Would it be acceptable to have the word "premium" as the first level status and "pro" as the next level? As a native speaker, do you find it awkward to have pro as the next level of premium?

**EDIT**

The web service I am developing currently has a single plan named pro. The reason I named so is that the plan has all the essentials of the service and the next level plan will only add extra features to the existing service. The dilemma I have is that I can only implement the first level plan at current state. If I name it to something like basic with the next level in my mind, I suppose the sales  will not be satisfying without actually having the next level plan. So I should name it to emphasize its essential nature but at the same time should consider the future adoption of the next level plan. That's the reason why I came up with the name 'pro' and now am asking which name might be suitable for the higher plan. Since I do not have to stick to the name 'pro' for the first level plan, any suggestions of the names that meet the relationship I described : essential - advanced will be much appreciated.

Comment: "Master" level comes to mind.  But what do you do after that?

Comment: If you can provide us with the names of the other plans, that might help us think of a word that fits the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Elite* comes to mind. A person can be a pro without being elite. Think of a normal professional athlete vs a superstar. Both are *pro*, but only one is *elite*.

Comment: *Elite* is good, but might sound a little gamer-y.  Which could be fine for your intended purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Pro means,

> (of a person or an event) **professional**.

Premium means,

> a sum added to an ordinary price or charge.

It won't look good if the highest level is premium and the mid level is pro. Pro should be above premium. So, it should be:

**Free/Basic < Premium < Professional**

Or you may use premier instead,

**Free/Basic < Professional < Premier**

Premier means,

> first in importance, order, or position; leading.

E.g. Windows 7 editions:

> Windows 7 Home **Basic**
>
> Windows 7 Home **Premium**
>
> Windows 7 **Professional**
>
> Windows 7 **Enterprise**
>
> Windows 7 **Ultimate**

Edit: Master may be used as suggested by Andrew.

**Free/Basic < Professional < Master**